# Which test should I use

Tags: statistical-significance

I am doing research on a specific test, which gives a result either positive or negative and then the positive results are further categorized into organism types.
The positive results are either male or female. 
How can I test for significance?

Also the test takes some time to become positive, known as time to positivity (TTP) which can be categorized as follows: 0-12 hrs, 12-24 hrs etc.....
How can I test significance for these?

Comment: Significance of what? You need to give much more detail about what it is you're actually trying to do with this data.

Comment: On this site there's no need to say "thank you" at the end of your post - it 
might seem rude at first, but it's part of the philosophy of this site 
([tour]) to "Ask questions, get answers, no distractions". Can you also clarify whant you mean by significance in this context?

Comment: Before testing for significance you should formulate a hypothesis. Once you got that, see which null hypotheses of any test known to you is almost opposite to your hypothesis and than you can perform that test. In your question there is no hypothesis nor null hypothesis and this makes answering difficult. As you are dealing with categories and Counts, chances are, that there is some kind of chi-square test to answer the (hopefully soon improved) question.

Comment: The null hypothesis is that gender has nothing to do with the test positivity. Do I need to know if the difference between males and females number is significant

Comment: In order to answer whether gender is related to test positivity then you could either use a Chi-square test or logistic regression. I'm still not sure how time fits into your hypothesis though